# Triple A bond fund and interest rate risks

Tags: bonds

Suppose we have a bond fund with an average rating of triple A and a duration of 5 year. Is it reasonable to use the 5 year government bond yield as the rate affecting the value of the fund via the duration?

I.e 5 year government bond moves up 1 % means the fund loses 5 % in value.

Is there a rule of thumb to know which rate one should associate to a certain type of bond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration is sensitivity to "interest rate" overall, not one specific interest rate. So if interest rates move in parallel, then any rate will do. More specific than just an overall duration is what's called *key rate duration*. It gives you sensitivity to specific interest rates (e.g. 6M, 1Y, 5Y, 10Y) that are determined by the actual constituents of the fund. So a 5Y gov rate *might* be a decent barometer for calculating your interest rate risk, but depending on the fund's constituents, the risk may be spread across more tenors.

In addition, a corporate bond fund will have some level of *credit spread risk* on top of the govt interest rate risk. For a AAA fund, that risk should be relatively stable, but it's something else to be aware of.

Bottom line is that the 5Y govt rate might give you *most* of your interest rate sensitivity, but if you want a more precise sensitivity there are some other factors you might consider.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, but not necessarily.  If a fund owns mostly 1 month treasury bills and a small allocation to 30 year zero coupon bonds, it could have a 5 year duration.  Depending on the shape of the yield curve, this hypothetical portfolio may have a different yield than the 5 year treasury.